# laravel Class 'App\Categories' not found

Tags: laravel

When I try to call a function with categories data `$categories = Categories::all();` it returns an error that `Class 'App\Categories' not found`

Here is my CategoriesController code:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller as BaseController;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\Categories;


class CategoriesController extends BaseController
{
    public function listcategories() {
    $categories = Categories::all();
    dd($categories);
    return view('admin.list_categories')->with('listcategories', 
    $categories);
}
```

Here is my Categories model code ;

```
  namespace App; 
  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

  class Categories extends Model
  {
    protected $fillable = [
    'title',
    'description',
    'flag_image',
    'status'
 ];

const STATUSES = [
    'Active' => 'Active',
    'Inactive' => 'Inactive',
];

const DEFAULT_STATUS = 'Active';
/**
 * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
public $timestamps = false;

public static function rules() {
    return [
        'title' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'status' => 'required|string|in:' . implode(",", Categories::STATUSES)
    ];
}}
```

What is the problem ? I can't get it.

Comment: try composer dump-autoload

Comment: Did you add the `<?php` to the top of the class? Also, `composer du`

Comment: yes added  `<php ?>` what you say about `composer` ?

Comment: It should be `<?php`. Run the `composer du` command in terminal.

Comment: @Sohel0415 yes its worked on dump-autoload.Everytime ru this command ?

Comment: you don't need to run everytime but when you have namespace related problem, try this first

Comment: where is your Categories.php inside what directory? Laravel uses composer autoload to find/list classes and your names space should be same as your directory structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because models are autoloading via **composer**

in some cases you need to run 
`composer dump-autoload` after changes in order to make it work